# private function declaration gcc vs msvc

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I'm not C programmer, and I'm trying to apply patch to project that compiles fine with MSVC, but patch is provided for *nix. When I try to compile patched project with `nmake` I get this error:

`error C2054: expected '(' to follow '__private'`

Code that raises this error is this:

```
private drawlist *
drawlist_append(p2mem *mem, drawlist_head *head)
{
    drawlist *d = p2mem_alloc(mem, sizeof(drawlist));
    if (!d) return 0;
    memset(d, 0, sizeof(drawlist));
    d->color = gx_no_color_index;
    d->next = 0;
    d->prev = head->last;
    head->last = d;
    (d->prev) ? (d->prev->next = d) : (head->first = d);
    return d;
}
```

By googling, I suspect that MSVC doesn't accept this kind of declaration, but I have no idea how to change the code, because as mentioned I'm not C/C++ programmer. Can anyone assist how to change this `private` function call so that it is valid for MSVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `drawlist_append` is a member function declared inside `class`, 
you could try:

```
private:
drawlist* drawlist_append(p2mem *mem, drawlist_head *head)
```

If drawlist_append is a standalone function, you just remove `private`, you could try this:

```
drawlist* drawlist_append(p2mem *mem, drawlist_head *head)
```

The other possibility is that patch provider meant `static` instead of `private`.
You could try add below macro for *nix C:

```
#define private static
```

Comment: It seems then that it is standalone function and your last line passes fine, but as there are many functions, for example `private int`, `private void`,... Should I remove all "private <type>` lines?

Comment: if they are all not inside class, I guess so, it's actually C code not C++

Answer (score 1):

C++ would require this in the *declaration*

```
private:
 drawlist * drawlist_append(p2mem *mem, drawlist_head *head) { ..... }
```

everything following that `private` is, well, private.

C doesn't have concepts such as `private`, `public` etc.

Answer (score 1):

This code relies on the following:

```
#ifndef private
# define private static
#endif
```

Unfortunately, there's already an expansion in place with Microsoft's compiler.

I would propose that you add

```
#ifdef private
#undef private
#endif
#define private static
```

to the top of your file, or just replace "private" with "static" throughout.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work too, and it's cleaner and easier to make